# The meaning of the regular expression in TCL/EXPECT

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I read a tcl test script, it uses EXPECT. some of the code is:

```
expect ".*hello.*yes.*morning.*"
```

The "*" wild card is matching everything, but what about the "." in front of it? what does this mean? what kind of pattern wanted to be matched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the `expect` command's default matching style is `-glob`, so those dots are in fact literal dots. Help with glob-style matching can be found in the [`string match`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40) documentation.

If you want your pattern to be considered as a [regular expression](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), you have to say:

```
expect -re ".*hello.*yes.*morning.*"
```

Comment: if expect commands matching styple is -glob, so does this mean I have a add a keyword "match" after the "expect" like this: expect match ".*hello.*yes.*morning.*" ?

Comment: based on the book "exploring expect", the "*" is the wildcard to match everything, but what about the "." in front of it? It is just a literal dots? Does this mean the input should start with ".", for example  the input is ".aaaahello.bbbyes.cccmorning.", then it matches? And it does not match in any other cases?

Comment: @ratzip, "match" is a subcommand for the "string" command only. The "expect" command does NOT use it. As I wrote in my answer, for glob matching, a dot is a literal dot.

Answer (score 3):

The * is not a wildcard in regular expressions, . is, the * after . means 0 or more occurances of the previous character/character class. So here it means: 0 or more occurences of any sign. Also note that depending on regex options, . often does not include newlines.

Comment: may I ask a stupid question, the regular expressions used in TCL/EXPECT is the same as that used in other programming language?

Comment: Hm, I have not noticed any significant different behaviour in the year I'm using TCL now, but I can't guarantee it. Many times regex implementations differ over different languages, albeit in features you most likely won't use very often.

Comment: @ratzip -- There are lots of minor variations in regex syntax between languages, as well as two different strands (perl-ish v. grep-ish) that differ mostly in which characters require a preceding backslash, `\`.  Here's tcl wiki page with info specific to tcl: http://wiki.tcl.tk/396

Comment: Tcl regexes are close but not exactly like Perl regexes. Documentation at http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Comment: @glenn: The big difference between Tcl REs and Perl REs is that Perl's are implemented using a stack machine whereas Tcl's are compiled to an automata that can flipflop between greedy and non-greedy modes. This is a _fundamental_ difference with enormous numbers of subtle consequences (both good and bad).

Comment: @KillianDS: it sounds like you might be confusing _glob_ patterns and _regular expressions_. they appear similar but are not. Glob patterns are mostly commonly used to match filenames. Tcl regular expressions are similar (but not precisely) the same as other regular expressions, but all regular expressions are different than glob patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is not a wildcard in regular expressions.  You're thinking of shell operations with filename wildcards, but that's *not* how `*` works in regular expressions.  Totally different animals.  In your regex it's the `.` that matches any character, then the `*` that says 'match 0 or more of the preceding character.

Here's some info on regexes:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

and here's page directly addressing the confusion regex newbies may have between regular expressions and shell filename-matching patterns:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch32_02.htm